# Text compare with pdf export

Tags: compare, diff

I want to be able to export a text compare to PDF.

Until now I tried: Notepad++, Tortoise Git/SVN, Winmerge and Diffchecker desktop.

Only Winmerge and Diffchecker desktop are able to do it, but since you cannot adjust scaling for printing there the text is cut off in the export.

Answer (score 0):

Winmerge has both font & zoom plus page size settings to get a good PDF customized output.

[image]

[image]